# iOS and Android Push Notifications from server Java

Tags: ios, spring, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

- am using spring boot & spring project
- i have developed one rest call &
- FCM_URL = https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
- Server Key = My Firebase Key

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/push/notification")
  public void sendNotification(@RequestParam String Mobiletoken, @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody FcmRequestObject message) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
      OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);
      System.out.println("Here sending notification request/...");
      RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder().add("to", tokens).add("data", obj.toString()).build();
      System.out.println(obj.toString());
      Request request = new Request.Builder().url(ApplicationConstants.FCM_URL)
              .addHeader("Authorization", "key=" + ApplicationConstants.FCM_SERVER_KEY).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").post(body)
              .build();
      try {
          Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
          System.out.println(response.isSuccessful() + " - " + response.code());
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  ```
- Input : Device Token & json body
- Android Devices able to get Notifications
- **But IOS Devices not able to get notifications [we have tested from firebase console with server key & device token its working, only from server they not able to get]**
- need to any changes in Rest Call for IOS?
- in PHP have

  ```
   $arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
  ```
- **Help on this and save my Days**, if any changes in rest and can you give sample..
- thank you in advance..

Comment: Are you aware that iOS and Android deal with notifications differently? In what method are you receiving the notification in your iOS app. Please add your code.

Comment: Agreeing with @Barns52 Android and iOS handle the FCM payload differently, hence it is advisable to have separate payload for the two platforms. You're currently sending a `data` message payload that Android is receiving properly. Try sending a `notification` message payload with a `"priority": "high"` to iOS.

Comment: You can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172021/3073945

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem.

As -AL suggested, I used attribute "notification" in place of "data" and it worked for me.

Sample push message for iOS:
"{"notification":{"title":"Title of notification","body":"Your message","attribute3":"vale","attribute4":"vale"....},"to":"Device Token","priority":"high"}"

In the above payload, attribute 3 and 4 are extra attributes that we can add to do perform any action or event like navigating to any particular screen based on the notification.